# Why dired+ not save sort mode?

Tags: dired, sorting

windows 10, 
Emacs 26.1,
Dired+

Suppose I has 3 files and sort it by name in dired mode.

Smt like this:

[image]

OK. Now I sort it by date, press `s`

Here result:

[image]

OK.
Now I edit file `3.txt` and after save data in this file I return to dired by press `dired-jump` (C-x C-j). And here result.

[image]

As you can see it again sort by **name** but I need to sort by **date**. Why dired+ not save my sort mode?

Answer (score 1):

`dired-jump` (`C-x C-j`) just invokes command `dired`, which gives you a **new** Dired buffer, with the default switches from **`dired-listing-switches`**.

You can customize `dired-listing-switches` to whatever you want.

If you expect to return to an existing Dired buffer, which already uses the switches you want, then use `C-x b` to switch to that buffer.

If you want to automatically change the default switches to use each time you use `s` in Dired (that is, automatically modify `dired-listing-switches`), so that another, arbitrary use of `dired` uses the latest ones, then you'll need to program that. You can, for example, advise `dired-sort-toggle-or-edit` (which is bound to `s` in Dired mode).